# Pentaho Kettle Modified Java Script setVariable

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I want to create a variable (not new field) on the fly from an existing field in the data stream and then modify the variable.
The reason, I need single quotes `'` around a list of strings that I can use in an `IN` clause in a Sql statement. Kettle eliminates the single quote in a field but they are preserved in a variable. My best guess is using setVariable in the Modified Java Script, but from there I am stumped.

Comment: Can you provide the steps used, and clarify where or how the single quotes are eliminated?  I regularly output text files containing fields with single quotes -- Kettle does not eliminate them from the stream fields or from the output.

Answer (score 0):

I must not have enough rep to attach files to answers. Too bad because I have a ktr that does this nicely.

I first add the "'" as a new field to the rows. I then pass the rows with the values I want to transform into a list into a Group By step. I choose an aggregate of 'Concatenate strings separated by' and use a value of `','`, and give the result a new name like 'list'.

Then I pass that result row to a Calculator step where the calculation is A + B + C. I specify the "'" field for values A and C and the list field for value B. Then I pass that result to a Set Variables step.

In the parent job I get a variable that looks just as you would expect: `'val1','val2','val3'`. No JavaScript needed.